# sort a list by attribute using a customer priorty

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of objects representing cards, each card has the properties suit and value, how do i sort them using a custom priority ( shown below)

Here is my custom priority:
priority = {"2":0, "3":1, "4":2,"5":3 ,"6":4, "7":5,"8": 6,"9": 7,"10": 8,"11" :9, "12":10,"13":11,"1":12}

and I want to sort the objects by their value

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sort` with a key function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) along the following lines:

```
cards.sort(key=lambda c: priority[c.value])
```

If you want higher priorities first, do

```
cards.sort(key=lambda c: priority[c.value], reverse=True)
```

With added suit, make the key a tuple:

```
cards.sort(key=lambda c: (priority[c.value], card.suit))
```

Comment: thanks !!!! how would i make it so that if the cards have the same value, they are then sorted via their suit instead?

Comment: @Julian Added an example for that case

Comment: you're the man, however i mean if more than 1 card has the same value, just sort the cards with the same value via suit, not the entire list... is this possible?

Comment: Not sure I get you. The last example sorts the list by value-priority and suit. So only cards with  same value will even consider the suit, as the key tuples are sorted lexicographically.

Comment: my bad, i was forgetting to clear the list after each poker hand, my bad. thank you so much for your help!